# How can you call class methods on mailers when they're not defined as such?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-method, instance-methods

When sending mail in Rails, usually one would do something like this:

```
UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver
```

But if we look inside `UserMailer` we can see this:

```
def password_reset(user) # not self.password_reset
  # ...
end
```

Notice that the method name is not prefixed with `self`. Looking at it, it seems like you need to instantiate the object first as below. How does Rails do this?

```
UserMailer.new.password_reset(user).deliver
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's a great question. In the source (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb), Rails uses method_missing to create a new instance of the ActionMailer. Here's the relevant excerpt from the source:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args) # :nodoc:
  if respond_to?(method_name)
    new(method_name, *args).message
  else
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. But why not just make it a class method? What do we gain from this approach?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand entirely. Do you mean why not make it an instance method? So, like UserMailer.new.password_reset(user).deliver?

Comment: I mean why use method missing? Keep it `UserMailer.password_reset(user).deliver` but change `def method` to `def self.method`

Comment: `deliver` has been defined as a class method in the ActionMailer module, see my answer.

Comment: I don't necessarily understand all the design decisions here, but if you inspect the source, there's a lot going on behind the scenes. It seems that they are creating new instances of the mailer, and they need method_missing to do that, since your class method doesn't do that. I think the best thing would be to dig into the source yourself. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the `self.deliver` method is deprecated, have a look at the code given below. Since `deliver` method is defined as a class method you don't have to instantiate the mailer class.

**action_mailer/deprecated_api.rb**

```
module ActionMailer
  module DeprecatedApi #:nodoc:
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
  # Deliver the given mail object directly. This can be used to deliver
  # a preconstructed mail object, like:
  #
  #   email = MyMailer.create_some_mail(parameters)
  #   email.set_some_obscure_header "frobnicate"
  #   MyMailer.deliver(email)
  def deliver(mail, show_warning=true)
    if show_warning
      ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn "#{self}.deliver is deprecated, call " <<
        "deliver in the mailer instance instead", caller[0,2]
    end

    raise "no mail object available for delivery!" unless mail
    wrap_delivery_behavior(mail)
    mail.deliver
    mail
  end
```

> **Sending mail**
>
> Once a mailer action and template are defined, you can deliver your message or create it and save it for delivery later:

```
mail = Notifier.welcome(david)  # => a Mail::Message object
mail.deliver  # sends the email

#Above 2 steps can be combined
Notifier.welcome(david).deliver
```

> **You never instantiate your mailer class. Rather, you just call the  method you defined on the class itself.**
>
> The method `password_reset` returns a Mail::Message object which can then just be told **deliver** to send itself out.