# ActionMailer static methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading the rails doc about ActionMailer and I came out with a question when I read the following code:

```
# Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome Email after save
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
```

the question is: are the methods declared in the ActionMailer class all static? Because the action `welcome_email` is called on a class.

Comment: For all intents & purposes, I'd say the naming conventions of the functions need to remain independent to each other. If you're getting a conflict (or potential conflict), what is wrong with creating a different function name? My .02!

Answer (score 2):

The methods aren't **really** static, but ActionMailer defines a `method_missing` implementation that searchs its instance methods; if found, they'll call it. So, in practice, it works like static methods.

**EDIT**

I did a little digging 'round stackoverflow and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088619/how-can-you-call-class-methods-on-mailers-when-theyre-not-defined-as-such). I recommend you reading it =]