# ActionMailer are the methods static?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'notifications@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
   @user = user
   @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
   mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

To send the email I write `UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver` so my question is: are the methods declared in the Mailer Controller static? Becausei I call `welcome_email` on a class, so I am cunfused

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you call class methods on mailers when they're not defined as such?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088619/how-can-you-call-class-methods-on-mailers-when-theyre-not-defined-as-such)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, but in practice it works as if they were. You have the answer here: [How can you call class methods on mailers when they're not defined as such?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088619/how-can-you-call-class-methods-on-mailers-when-theyre-not-defined-as-such) .

Basically, the Mailer has a `method_missing` defined that if the method called doesn't exist, it will create an instance of the mailer and call the method on it.

Comment: When is `method_missing` called? Is it called by Rails everytime I invoce a mailer method? If so where is the piece of code that describes what I have just said cuz I can't see anything such that in the base.rb?

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb , line 498
          
```method_missing``` is called (if defined) everytime in Ruby when a method is not defined. It is not a Mailer or Rails thing, it is part of how Ruby works. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-method_missing
       ```method_missing``` is used occasionally when some automagical behaviour is needed (like this one in the Rails' Mailer, or the old ```find_by_whatever_field``` in ActiveRecord).